# What does this means while printing from a str1 variable in python str1[0 : -1 : 2] and how it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str1 = ‘This is Pyhton’
print ("Slice of String : ", str1[1 : 4 : 1])
print ("Slice of String : ", str1[0 : -1 : 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array slice. It means

```
str1[start:stop:step]
```

Takes `str1[1 : 4 : 1]`, starting from character in position `1`, not going past `4`, by step `1`.

```
print ("Slice of String : ", str1[0 : -1 : 2])
```

Means starting from character in position `0` (The first character), not going past the last character (position `-1` is the last character since it goes cycle), by step `2`.

```
Position:  0    1    2   3   4   5  6  7  8   9   10  11  12  13
String:    T    h    i   s       i  s     P   y   h   t   o   n
Position:  -14 -13  -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```